# By using RDotnet and C# , How can i show my R Code output in c# RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, r.net

is it possible to get a variable value from rodotnet and show the value in RichTextBox??

```
 CharacterVector charVec = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new[] { txtgetUser.Text.ToString() });
        engine.SetSymbol("username", charVec);
        engine.Evaluate("user <- getUser(username)");
        engine.Evaluate("user$toDataFrame()");
        engine.Evaluate("friends <- user$getFriends()");
```

in above code i am using a text box(txtgetUser) which is getting a username from twitter.. and other code is getting its followings.. now i want to show my output in Richtextbox.. 
how can i show my output from R code in RichTextBox??

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, I hope it helps:

```
            engine.Evaluate("x<-c(1:10)");
            string[] text = engine.Evaluate("x").AsCharacter().ToArray();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string value in text)
            {
                builder.Append(value);
            }
            richTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```